Next.js Static Site Generation (SSG) is actually a React application in the client-side?
I've been discussing the Next.js SSG generation with my team, and I'm quite confused.
I haven't found this information in the web out there.
I've been doing some researches through AI and I got this response:
"Yes, that’s correct. When you generate a static site using Next.js (or similar frameworks), the site is initially served as static HTML to the browser.
However, after the static content is served, Next.js “rehydrates” the static HTML into a fully interactive React application on the client side. This process is often referred to as hydration."
So, whenever I have dynamic components (for example, I have a component that applies a style when hovered, so I use a state to define a boolean to check whether it is hovered or not), will React be managing these components through these listeners?
Is this correct?
Next.js => HTML => React (on needed components)
I'm asking this because we are discussing whether or not we should pass an object as a prop in a component instead of inline props to improve performance
I'm trying to ensure that the result of a Next.js Static Site in the end is whether or not a static HTML with some React listeners around it.

Yes next is fully fledged react application

Thank you, antokhio. I thought that the generated HTML, CSS and JS generated by Next.js using SSG was a simply web vanilla and does not contain a React.
